# Time complexity of algorithm, big Oh notation

Tags: time-complexity

I'm trying to calculate the big Oh complexity, and trying to prove if the given functions satisfy the condition of Big Oh,  What can be the complexity of x^O(1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`O(1)` is a *constant*, so `x^O(1)` will be `x^C` where `C` is some constant, and thus you have a *polynomial complexity* (with *unknown* power, however):

```
O(x^O(1)) == O(x^C) where C is some constant
```